# Syntax error with "gdalwarp"

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, gdalwarp

I want to project a raster from Sinusoidal to UTM. I used the following command in Python:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:32643 -of GTiff D:/IMAGE.tif D:/IMAGE2.tif
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone who can help?

Comment: The syntax error is in your Python code, not the gdalwarp invocation. You need to share more code around that. This is probably rather a generic programming question for stackoverflow

Comment: There is no code around. I was simply using this command to reproject the raster.

Comment: If you use the command in Python, then there is Python code around it. The error is in that code.

Answer (score 3):

In Python you should use **os module** and an adequate string combination, for **gdalwarp** parameters, to get a good performance. For example, I use next adapted code in my QGIS plugin and it works perfectly. In this case, it is employed for transforming UTM 12 N projection (EPSG:32612) in my raster to UTM Utah North projection (EPSG: 32142).

```
import os

layer = iface.activeLayer()

provider = layer.dataProvider()

source_path = " -of GTiff " + provider.dataSourceUri()
target_path = "/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/utah_dem_UtmNorth2.tif"

CRS = layer.crs()
source_epsg = CRS.postgisSrid()
new_espg = 32142
target_epsg = " -t_srs EPSG:" + str(new_espg)

cmd = "gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:" + \
                        str(source_epsg) + \
                        target_epsg + \
                        source_path + \
                        " " + \
                        target_path

print cmd

os.system(cmd)
```

To test the adequate command execution, comment last line:

```
os.system(cmd)
```

and observe and correct **gdalwarp** syntax until you can get expected result.

**Editing Note:**

In your case, I think that next code could work:

```
import os

source_path = " -of GTiff D:/IMAGE.tif " 
target_path = "D:/IMAGE2.tif "

source_epsg = 6974  #Sinusoidal Projection
new_espg = 32643
target_epsg = " -t_srs EPSG:" + str(new_espg)

cmd = "gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:" + \
                        str(source_epsg) + \
                        target_epsg + \
                        source_path + \
                        " " + \
                        target_path

print cmd

os.system(cmd)
```